# jQuery on check, add or update array object item

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxs and on change event like so:

```
$(".checkbox").on('change', function () {
          UpdateHolder($(this).attr('id'), customerID, this.checked);
});


function UpdateHolder(questionid, customerid, checked) {
        holder.push({ questionid: questionid, customerid: customerid, checked: checked });
        console.log(holder);
    }
```

with this, I am able to add an item to the array, but my question is how would I update an item ? I only want to update if a checkbox is selected or not.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to not update the list at all, but instead to create a new one on each action. Try this:

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {  
    holder = $('.checkbox').map(function() {
        return { 
            questionid: this.id,
            customerid: customerID, // I presume this is a global variable?
            checked: this.checked
        };
    }).get();
    console.log(holder);
});
```

Comment: True, it doesn't match the topic of your question, but it does meet the goal and is, in practice, a far better pattern to use.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks - although I missed `get()` from my code. Here's an updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lw5y2c7/1/

Answer (score 0):

To be able to update existing entries, your function should look something like this:

```
function UpdateHolder(questionid, customerid, checked) {
    var index = holder.indexOf({
        questionid: questionid,
        customerid: customerid,
        checked: checked
    });
    index = index > -1 ? index : holder.indexOf({
        questionid: questionid,
        customerid: customerid,
        checked: !checked
    });
    //item was not found, insert it
    if( index < 0 ) {
        holder.push({ 
            questionid: questionid, 
            customerid: customerid, 
            checked: checked 
        });
    //item was found, update it
    } else {
        holder[index] = {
            questionid: questionid,
            customerid: customerid,
            checked: checked
        };
    }
    console.log(holder);
}
```